# no match for call to vector of inner class objects

Tags: c++

I have a class and i tried to construct this class with Point2D object vector.

```
        class Polygon{//Polygon.h
            public:
              //-----------POINT CLASS----------
              class Point2D{
              public:
                Point2D(double param_x = 0, double param_y = 0);
                double getX() const;
                double getY() const;
                void setX(double setX);
                void setY(double setY);
              private:
                double x;
                double y;
              };
            Polygon(vector<Polygon::Point2D>& pointVec);
            private:
                int capacity;
                Point2D* points;//For dynamic array
           }

Polygon::Polygon(vector<Polygon::Point2D>& pointVec){//Vector constructor from polygon.cpp
  capacity = pointVec.size();
  points = new Polygon::Point2D[capacity];
  for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    points[i] = pointVec[i];
}//Vector of 2D points
```

But when i tried to construct an object of Polygon object with vector of Point2D objects its give me an error like

```
error: no match for call to '(Polygon) (std::vector<Polygon::Point2D>&)'
    return newPoly(newObj);
```

up here newPoly is Polygon object and newObj is vector of Point2D objects.

This here where code give error.

```
const Polygon Polygon::operator +(const Polygon& otherPoly) const{
 vector<Polygon::Point2D> newObj;
 Polygon newPoly;
 if(capacity > otherPoly.getCapacity()){
   for(int i = 0; i < otherPoly.getCapacity(); i++){
     Point2D obj(points[i].getX() + otherPoly[i].getX(), points[i].getY() + otherPoly[i].getY());
     newObj.push_back(obj);
   }
   for(int j = otherPoly.getCapacity() + 1; j < capacity; j++){
     Point2D obj_2(points[j].getX() + otherPoly[j].getX(), points[j].getY() + otherPoly[j].getY());
     newObj.push_back(obj_2);
   }

   return newPoly(newObj);

 } else if(capacity < otherPoly.getCapacity()){
   for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
     Polygon::Point2D obj(points[i].getX() + otherPoly[i].getX(), points[i].getY() + otherPoly[i].getY());
     newObj.push_back(obj);
   }
   for(int j = capacity + 1; j < otherPoly.getCapacity(); j++){
     Polygon::Point2D obj_2(points[j].getX() + otherPoly[j].getX(), points[j].getY() + otherPoly[j].getY());
     newObj.push_back(obj_2);
   }

   return newPoly(newObj);

 } else if(capacity == otherPoly.getCapacity()){
   for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
     Polygon::Point2D obj(points[i].getX() + otherPoly[i].getX(), points[i].getY() + otherPoly[i].getY());
     newObj.push_back(obj);
   }

   return newPoly(newObj);

 }
}
```

Comment: Side note: Don't use raw pointers. In your case you could use a vector. See http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.

Comment: Please show the code that triggers the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `return newPoly(newObj)`. This is not calling the `Polygon` constructor that is taking a `vector`. This tries to find an `operator(std::vector<Point2D>)` inside `Polygon`. If you want to call the constructor you need to `return Polygon(newObj);` or `return Polygon{newObj};`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared the `Polygon(vector<Polygon::Point2D>& pointVec)` constructor within the class. Try to add

```
Polygon(vector<Polygon::Point2D>& pointVec);
```

Into the Polygon class **declaration**

Comment: I've done what you said and it's still giving same error

Comment: In the question as currently written that ctor is declared in the class.

Comment: Actually I didn't declare a vector inside class. I just want to pass parameter to constructor but it doesn't recognize.